# Replacement for Zend_Cache::factory in Zend Framework 3

Tags: zend-framework3, zend-cache

I am looking for a solution to replace the Zend 1/2 cache in a Zend 3 application. The old application is using

```
$cache = Zend_Cache::factory('Core', 'File, $frontendOptions, $backendOptions)
```

to get the cache instance. How could I get the same instance in Zend Framework 3?

Comment: have you tried https://github.com/zendframework/zend-cache ?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look of this code. Full description can be found [here](https://docs.zendframework.com/zend-cache/)

```
$cache = \Zend\Cache\StorageFactory::factory([
    'adapter' => [
        'name' => 'filesystem',
        'options' => [
            'namespace' => 'builder',
        ],
    ],
    'options' => [
        'cache_dir' => 'data/cache',
    ],
    'plugins' => [
        'exception_handler' => [
            'throw_exceptions' => true,
        ],
        'Serializer',
    ],
]);
```